# Calling .setPersistenceEnabled(false) when logging out of app, not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart, persistence

In my Flutter/Dart mobile app I make use of Firebase RTDB persistence to enable offline use of the app.

My understanding is that to enable persistence you have to make the call, as per the following piece of code, before using any database references to eg. query the database. I use the following piece of code to enable persistence immediately after loading the app and it works fine:

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
bool _success = await firebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
print(_success); // Prints true, so persistence is set 'on'.
```

When I logout of the app I attempt to turn persistence off with:

```
bool _success = await firebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(false);
print(_success); // Prints false, so persistence is still 'on', ie. the call failed.
```

I assume the reason persistence cannot be turned off is because there have been calls to db references prior to trying to switch it off.

This leads to three questions, I guess:

1. Should I be worried about turning it off at all, when I logout? The reason I attempt it is good house-keeping, mainly. I clean up shared preferences, close keepsyncd's, etc when logout is run. Also, though, the user can have multiple userids to login and I want to make sure that I am not retaining persisted data from their previous login id.
2. Related to 1, does setting persistence to false clear the cache of
   data and potential queued calls to the db?
3. If the answers to 1 and 2 are 'yes', how can I switch persistence off given the code I'm using to do so keeps telling me it failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to handle this is to enable persistence once a user logs in.

Once disk persistence has been enabled and your app has used the database, it cannot be turned off. The documentation says this about it:

> The returned `Future` will complete with `true` if the operation was successful or `false` if the persistence could not be set (**because database references have already been created**).

That last bit is clearly the case for you: you've been using the database already, which means that disk persistence is on.

To your specific questions:

1. Unfortunately the data in the local cache cannot be cleared up through the API at the moment. It is a valid [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/), but for now you'll have to assume that any data on the device can be seen by any user on that device (or device profile).
2. Disabling disk persistence keep the client from adding data to the cache. It does not clear any existing data in the cache.

Comment: Thanks, Frank. That is kinda what I thought. I will look at raising a feature request.

Comment: Sorry, forgot. Done now. Looking forward to seeing you reach 500k. :-)